# sqllite3 not grouping by count

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to return the number of unique values in column but it's not working as hoped.  For example:

```
select columnName, count(columnName) as CountOf from tableName group by columnName
result = c.fetchone()
print result
```

....will return:

```
(627, 1)
(399, 1)
(1714, 1)
(1714, 1)
(88, 1)
(88, 1)
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS some_alias FROM table_name
result = c.fetchone()
print result
```

...which returns:

```
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
```

Desired output (in regards to the first statement) would be something like:

```
(627, 1)
(399, 1)
(1714, 2)
(88, 2)
```

The code I'm using is:

```
def alertsSQL(inputA):

    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    c = conn.cursor()
    allT = "SELECT * FROM Alerts"

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE Alerts (SID INT, Signature TEXT)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Alerts (SID, Signature) VALUES (?,?)", (inputA))
    conn.commit()

    c.execute('SELECT SID, count(*) as CountOf from Alerts group by SID')
    result=c.fetchall()

    print result
```

The lists being feed into '`inputA`' are of the nature:

```
[1714, 'NETBIOS SMB-DS Session Setup']
```

N.B. In the code above I've just reduced the number of columns, for clarity sake.  The data is inserted correctly, which I verify by:

```
for row in c.execute(allT):
        print row
```

Which produces each row in the table, e.g. one row being:

```
(1714, u'NETBIOS SMB-DS Session Setup')
```

Comment: How can you be using `c.fetchone()` but get multiple rows returned?

Comment: I've no idea I tried using c.fetchmany() and c.fetchall() to rule out any obsucure bug but they just return the same, as expeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit and many thanks to @JonClements for the solution.

In the original post `alertsSQL(inputA)` was being called multiple times as a result of a for loop, and `inputA` itself was a list generated in each for loop.  In the code below the list being received (i.e. '`ALL`') is a nested list.  It also modifies and organises appropriately the contents from `alertsSQL()` - which was previously being executed multiple times as a result of the aforementioned for loop.

```
def init_db(filename=':memory:'):

    db = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE Alerts (SID INT, Signature TEXT)")
    return db

db = init_db()

someFunction() # Function generates a nested list i.e. ALL
db.executemany("INSERT INTO Alerts (SID, Signature) VALUES (?,?)", (ALL))  

c = db.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT SID, count(*) as CountOf from Alerts group by SID')
result=c.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using:

```
select columnName, count(columnName) as CountOf from tableName group by columnName
```

This should be:

```
select columnName, count(*) as CountOf from tableName group by columnName
```

For proper aggregation of the GROUP BY to occur.

Comment: Thank-you, Jon.  For some reason though it's still returning the same output as in my first example.  To rule out compatablity issues I'm using EcLipse Luna (4.4.0), sqlite3 2.6.0, and Python 2.7.8 (64 bit) - all of which has been working fine.  Any more ideas? :)

Comment: @Soap can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25309708/edit) your question to include the exact code you're running.. The SQL provided in this answer is correct - the problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: It's updated :) (I wasn't sure if you get the notification with an update of a post...just I was informed by another user to provide notifications with the @ symbol or as a comment in the answer)

Comment: @Soap okay, gimme a mo... that's a strange function... need to pop to the shops briefly

Comment: Good observation, thanks! And I hope your shopping trip went well :) It's being called 6 times, I've taken the select statement (with `result=c.fetchall()` and the print) outside of alertsSQL...but it now only returns `(88, 1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59373/discussion-between-jon-clements-and-soap).